# Cant get element using template literals

Tags: javascript

Im injecting some number of buttons in my DOM using a for loop

```js
function injectBtn () {
  var output = '';
  for(var i = 0 ; i < someNumber ; i++){
      output += `<button id="button${i}">`;
  }
  document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = output;
}
```

Further I want to add event listeners to them like this, but nothing happens when I click them.

```js
function addEvents () {
  for (var i=0 ; i < someNumber ; i++) {
      var btn = document.getElementById(`button${i}`);
      btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
         console.log('click');
      }
   }
}
```

I checked in my console, and I'm sure the buttons have been added to the DOM. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You're missing `</button>` in the first loop.

Comment: Also if you actually click "Run code snippet" for your second part, it shows a syntax error. If you copied your code directly, this is probably the cause?

Comment: The syntax error is a missing `)` at the end of `addEventListener`

Comment: Fixing the errors listed above, it works: https://jsfiddle.net/m8xgnm64/